# return custom class allocation memory leaks

Tags: iphone, memory, sdk, calendar, memory-leaks

i am using kal calendar application. i am getting memory leak on following code. can anybody please suggest me what i have done wrong.

**holidayjsondatasource.m**

...

```
for (int i=0; i<[calendar_value count]; i++) {

NSDate *d = [[fmt dateFromString:[[calendar_value objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"EventDate"]] retain];                   

     [holidays addObject:[CalendarDetails 
                                        holidayNamed:[[calendar_value objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"UnitName"] 
                                        duration_date:[[calendar_value objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Checkinout"] 
                                        status:[[calendar_value objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"EventType"] 
                                        date:d des:[[calendar_value objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Description"]  
                                        bid:[[calendar_value objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"ID"]]];
                   [d release];


               }


           }
```

...

**Calendar Details.m**

......

```
+ (CalendarDetails*)holidayNamed:(NSString *)aname duration_date:(NSString *)aduration_date status:(NSString *)astatus date:(NSDate *)adate bid: (NSString *)abid note:(NSString *)anote image_status:(NSString *)aimage_status lmd:(NSString *)almd


{


CalendarDetails *cal =[ [[CalendarDetails alloc] initWithName:aname duration:aduration_date      status:astatus date:adate bid:abid note:anote image_status:aimage_status lmd:almd] autorelease];

return cal;
```

}

........

Thanks & Regards,
Sathish

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you sent any console output and told us how exactly you know you have a memory leak.

It looks like not so much a memory leak as an over-release: you're calling `[d release]` but you shouldn't be releasing your `NSDate` this way -- you got it in such a way that it is autoreleased. Read the Cocoa Memory Management Guidelines.

Btw, using better variable names would make things easier all round. E.g. `date` instead of `d`.

Comment: Did removing "[d release]" make any difference?